# Deploy an apk to Android device using adb

Tags: android, deployment, installation, adb, apk

Hello I want to deploy an apk to my **physical** mobile device using this command:

```
adb install android-debug.apk
```

And I got this error :

```
adb install android-debug.apk
[100%] /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
pkg: /data/local/tmp/android-debug.apk
android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
Error: Could not access the Package Manager.  Is the system running?
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to physically unlock your device's lockscreen and make sure you have usb debugging enabled. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38710859/not-able-to-install-apks-via-adb) to where I read the answer, remember, search before you post.

Comment: The device is physically unlocked!